Addition Ending Symbols in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to include additional symbols in Gregorian Chant musixgre library; I am trying to use pgfornament package. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={22pt 7pt 192pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}%
\lettrine[lines=2]{U}{}
\begin{music}%
\hsize=1.55\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{t que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef
%\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\parindent10mm
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece\hsize=0.8\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\centering%not working in centering the synbol
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\pgfornament[width = 5cm, color = red-undar]{59}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:


What do you ask? That somebody draws the ornament for you? Do you need help restoring the \hsize to \linewidth to centre the image? Have you tried to size the image to a portion of \linewidth?

Solved:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={5pt 7pt 201pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}%
%\textcolor{red-undar}{\lettrine[lraise=0.81,lines=2]{U}{}}
\raisebox{0.3\Interligne}{\color{red-undar}\Huge U}%
\begin{music}%
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{t que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
%\parindent10mm
\hsize=1.53\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-2.06cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{II}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zstoppiece\hsize=1.58\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece
%\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece\hsize=0.8\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\en%
%\zstoppiece\hsize=1.53\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
%\notes\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (18.9,0) rectangle (-0.1,1.4);
\node at (current bounding box.center){\pgfornament[color=red-undar,width=7cm]{71}};
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


